# Erlang module calling a mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql-server, erlang, erlang-shell

I have an `erlang` module that will call a `stored procedure` in `Mysql`. The table has a column that is `NULL` by default or a `VARCHAR`. I would like to send `varchar` value or a `NULL` value from the erlang module. How do I send `NULL` value from `erlang`?

I think I should send an atom with value `NULL`, but not really sure.

Comment: You should mention which `mysql` module you use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql otp or odbc driver to connect to mysql then atom() null should be used.